# Distribution rhino and elephant, what test to use?

Tags: distributions, correlation

I was wondering if i could get some advise on which statistical test would be best to use for my data. Currently I have a grid with each cell having the the total number of rhino or elephant seen. This is monthly data from 2014 - 2017. I would like to determine whether rhino avoid cells where there is a higher presence of elephant. But i am not so sure which statistical test to use. I was thinking of looking at a correlation analysis.

Any advise would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain a correlation is the best approach. I am making a number of assumptions on the nature of your data, so this approach may not be correct. ¿Can you obtain the mean number of rhinos in cells where there are elephants vs. the mean number of rhinos in cells without elephants? (There is an argument for using the cells with neither, but for this initial exploration, they probably can be omitted.)

I realize this isn't an “answer” per se, but I think it may help you decide if a more involved/complicated/advanced analysis is necessary.